# Rails x-editable putting dashes into text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Rails gem 'bootstrap-editable-rails' (X-editable for Bootstrap).

I want to have a checkbox, but x-editable doesn't have a checkbox.  Instead you're supposed to use the "checklist" type (I really wish x-editable could handle boolean checkboxes).

This is my Rails Form code:

```
<td>
<a href="#" class="checklist" data-type="checklist" data-pk="1" data-resource="taskup" data-name="donebox" data-url="/taskups/<%= taskup.id %>" >
<%= taskup.donebox ? taskup.donebox : "False" %>
</a>
</td>
```

This is the jquery (coffee script)

```
$(".checklist").editable
type: 'checklist'
source:
  1: "True"
```

I get the x-editable pop-up, but instead of saving a "1" into the donebox field it puts in "---- '1'"

See the attached pic.

Thanks for the help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used bootstrap-editable 1.5.1 without the gem and hit a similar problem with the checkbox, caused by the fact that what was sent to the backend for a boolean value would be an array (because of the checklist type), i.e. in the rails log you'd get something like:

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"257", "geo_entity"=>{"is_current"=>["1"]}}
```

I worked around this by amending the checkbox fields in the params method, something like this (you'll see I'm also preparing the params in the format Rails expects for updating a resource):

```
  params: (params) ->
    value = params.value
    # is_current will be a checklist and therefore
    # the value will be an array such as ['1']
    if params.name == 'is_current'
      value = params.value.unshift()
    #originally params contain pk, name and value
    newParams = id: params.pk
    newParams['geo_entity'] = {}
    newParams['geo_entity'][params.name] = value
    newParams
```

I'd also like to see a cleaner way to do it!